# Grab a Specific Field from a JSON response in Python

Tags: python, json

I am sending an API request, and I receive the following response:

```
{ 
    'response':{ 
        'Container List':[ 
            { 
                'Driver ID':'038107264',
                'Status':True,
                'Truck':'4314008'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to print only the value in `Truck`, meaning I want to be able to print the value `4314008`.

Comment: This is a dict of dicts and other objects and a simple dict.get() should be able to help you.  Try `api_response.get('response').get('Container List')[0].get('Truck')` in a python shell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using requests to get this resonse

```
response = requests.get("whateverurl").json()
print(response["response"]["Container List"][0]["Truck"])
```